# How does one check Core Location authorization status in iOS versions below 14?

Tags: swift, authorization, core-location, ios14

I need to be able to check that a user has enabled location services via "Always Allow", but when creating an instance of CLLocationManager and then checking the .authorizationStatus, Xcode yells at me saying "'authorizationStatus' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer'. Is there any possible way of checking the authorization status without filtering out all users below iOS 14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before iOS 14, there's the class method `authorizationStatus` on `CLLocationManager`, it became an instance property after that. `CLLocationManager.h` has the details